# How do you find the variance of the expression below?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I'm trying to understand the calculation of $$Var \left (\int_{a}^{b} r_{s} ds\right) $$ where $r_{s} = \sigma W_{s}$ and $W_{s}$ is a standard 1-d Brownian motion. $\sigma$ is assumed to be constant.

and the solution is, $$\sigma^2 (b-a)^2(a+\frac{b-a}{3})$$

if I were to calculate, I would proceed like this:
$$
Var\left (\int_{a}^{b} r_{s} d_{s}\right) = Var \left (\sigma \int_{0}^{b} \int_{0}^{s} dW_{s} d_{s} - \sigma \int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{s} dW_{s} d_{s}\right)  
$$

How do we proceed further?

Comment: We can't guess what you denote $W_s$.

Comment: Hi Yves, I have updated the description.

Comment: Give the expression of $W_s$.

Comment: Hi Yves, Ws is standard Brownian motion , more info. available here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is rewriting the integral 
$$I = \int_a^b \sigma W_s \mathrm d s$$
using the Ito lemma.
$$\mathrm d f(t, W_t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (t, W_t) \mathrm d t + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t, W_t) \mathrm d W_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(t, W_t) \mathrm d t$$
Let $f(t,x) = \sigma tx$, we have that
$$ \sigma \mathrm d( t W_t) = \sigma W_t \mathrm d t + \sigma t \mathrm d W_t$$
Integrate between $a$ and $b$, and use Ito isometry :)

Comment: Hi Riccardo, This works! I wonder if $r_s$ is mean-reverting hull white short rate process, How would we calculate then?